# Not able to query for SQL ignore part of WHERE, if parameter is null

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Hi iam able to get the data between the time ranges.
but if i specify OR  :#{#orgSearch.createdTime.startDateTime}  IS NULL then im getting exceptions

this is my @Query

```
 @Query(value = "select o from Organization  o  where (o.createdAt  >:#{#orgSearch.createdTime.startDateTime} OR  :#{#orgSearch.createdTime.startDateTime}  IS NULL)  AND  (o.createdAt <:#{#orgSearch.createdTime.endDateTime}) OR  :#{#orgSearch.createdTime.endDateTime}  IS NULL ")
```

but iam getting  exceptions like below......

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: could not determine data type of parameter $2
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy139.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70)
    ... 95 more
```

any help Please?..

Comment: This is in JPQL? Then it shouldn't happen with Hibernate 5. If it's a native query, then there is no solution yet.

Comment: @coladict , yes this is JPA native query .is any solution is available for this? if any help please?

Comment: A possible work-around might be to set it to a non-null value before executing the query, which will determine the type, then set it to null, but I haven't tried it. The problem is with the postgresql server and they're refusing to fix it, because it "works as intended".

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to force PostgreSQL to interpret the parameter as a timestamp.

Refer this query and make yours accordingly.

```
SELECT *
FROM log
WHERE CASE
  WHEN $P{timestampFrom}::TIMESTAMP IS NULL THEN TIMESTAMP >= '-infinity'
  ELSE TIMESTAMP >= $P{timestampFrom}
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I tested this little workaround I mentioned earlier, and it works with the 5.0-5.3 type system. Assuming your timestamp class in Java is `java.time.Instant`, this can work

```
if (timestamps == null) {
    query.setParameter("ts", java.time.Instant.EPOCH);
}
query.setParameter("ts", timestamp);
```

From then on your next problem comes from closing the round brackets before the `OR` over here:

```
... (o.createdAt <:#{#orgSearch.createdTime.endDateTime}) OR  :#{#orgSearch.createdTime.endDateTime}  IS NULL
```

This all assumes you create the query using `entityManager.createNativeQuery(...)` on your own, or possibly use a named native query, since those Spring-generated implementations can't add the workaround for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this issue too with PostgreSQL and Instants.
The workaround I've used for this is to manually cast the parameter to timestamp
so if your query is like:

```
OR  :#{#orgSearch.createdTime.endDateTime}  IS NULL "
```

I'd try something like:

```
OR  CAST(:#{#orgSearch.createdTime.endDateTime} AS TIMESTAMP) IS NULL "
```

Hope this helps